# img src not displaying image but image is working on other website

Tags: html, css, image, src

I am trying to fetch an image from Instagram. The link to the image is working well on Instagram.

But when I go to use it in img tag it's not fetching.
This image doesn't have any .jpg .png etc. format.

[image: screenshot of the photo]

Photo Link: [here edited](https://instagram.fdac5-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-15/276009039_134006409174084_1326429066731031446_n.jpg?stp=dst-jpg_e35_s640x640_sh0.08&_nc_ht=instagram.fdac5-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=100&_nc_ohc=1vDDBoZo0awAX9FIoAY&edm=AABBvjUBAAAA&ccb=7-4&oh=00_AT_esZRWpwantgg9lIbVGFtkAj0dGZgkIC8qJEFtROt7Kg&oe=623EA32B&_nc_sid=83d603)

When I use it in HTML:

[image: screenshot of not working when use in img src tag]

How can I get the exact URL or fetch the image that doesn't have any .jpg .png etc. format?
Please help.

Comment: try putting .png on the end of the URL. What happens if you go to that URL? Also post code not screen shots of code.

Comment: _"The link to the image is working well on Instagram."_ - that doesn't mean that it is _supposed_ to work anywhere else. They might for example check if the request contains a valid session id - and if not, simply refuse to return the image, but give you a 403 Forbidden response or something similar.

Comment: What errors are you seeing in your browsers dev tools inspect facility? I doubt if Instagram is set up to be a free for all image server so I would not expect you to be allowed to use it as such.

Answer (score -1):

just open the image in a new tab
save it in the desktop from there
and relay it from your system.

Comment: Which will nearly always cause a copyright issue. Espacially as you unlawfully downlaoded and uploaded an image to rehost it on your server the possible copyright strike going to be much higher.

Comment: Is there any other way without downloading the image?

Comment: ask the owner of the image for usage permission and the image file...